# NativeScript tns run android --device/emulator doesn't work

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Im new to native script and ive been to trying to test on device or emulator. thats what im getting.

```
C:\Users\Muzi J\Documents\tns\HelloWorld>tns run android --device 4TE7N17106003969
Copying template files...
  - Installing tns-androidInstalling  tns-android
C:\Users\Muzi J\Documents\tns\HelloWorld
`-- tns-android@2.5.0


Exception: The plugin tns-android@2.5.0 is already installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try:

1. Delete your platforms folder and remove the line item inside the main package.json that has `"android": "2.5.x"`    Then do a `tns platform add android`
2. Try moving your code into a folder without a space in it.   I've seen some issues recently in the issues where spaces in the name were causing build issues.